# Show my subsections in the table of contents at the outline of my presentation

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

I want to show my subsections in the table of contents at the outline of my presentation.

In the sty file, he is my code

```
\AtBeginSection[]{
    \begin{frame}
        \tableofcontents[sectionstyle=show/shaded,subsectionstyle=show/shaded/hide,subsubsectionstyle=show/shaded/hide]
    \end{frame}
}
```

In the main file (tex) I have:

```
\begin{frame}{Overline}
   \tableofcontents[sectionstyle=show,subsectionstyle=show/shaded/hide,subsubsectionstyle=show/shaded/hide]
\end{frame}

\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Context}
\subsection{Justification of Study}
\subsection{Hypothesis}
\subsection{Objectives}

\section{Methodology}
\subsection{Study Area}
\subsection{Data}
\subsection{Tools}
\subsection{Methods}

\section{Results and Discussion}
\subsection{Results}
\subsection{Discussion}

\section{Conclusion and Perspectives}
\subsection{Conclusion}
\subsection{Perspectives}
```

[image: Outline that I currently have]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subsections are shown by default, so you can simply remove `subsectionstyle=show/shaded/hide` from your outline

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\AtBeginSection[]{
    \begin{frame}
        \tableofcontents[sectionstyle=show/shaded,subsectionstyle=show/shaded/hide,subsubsectionstyle=show/shaded/hide]
    \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Outline}
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Context}
\subsection{Justification of Study}
\subsection{Hypothesis}
\subsection{Objectives}

\section{Methodology}
\subsection{Study Area}
\subsection{Data}
\subsection{Tools}
\subsection{Methods}

\section{Results and Discussion}
\subsection{Results}
\subsection{Discussion}

\section{Conclusion and Perspectives}
\subsection{Conclusion}
\subsection{Perspectives}

    
\end{document}
```

[image]